# REST API - How to query for links discovery?

Tags: rest, hateoas

Suppose I have a RESTful HATEOAS API which has `/posts` endpoint which lists posts with a query shortcut `/posts/new`. How do I query the API to discover `/posts/new`?

My ideas:

**1)** Query `/posts` and get links from `_links` attribute (and the entities listed are necessary overhead):

```
GET /posts

{
  "docs": [
    ...
  ]
  "_links": {
    "new": { "rel": "posts", "href": "/posts/new" }
  }
}
```

**2)** Provide this in the API root together with list of resources:

```
GET /

{
  "resources": {
    "posts": {
      "_links": {
        "self": { "rel": "posts", "href": "/posts" }
        "new": { "rel": "posts", "href": "/posts/new" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**3)** I should not use the `/posts/new` query and instead use `/posts` and query params. However, if I change my server logic I would have to change client logic too and that would be serve-client coupling. For example:

- New messages will be requested by client by somehow providing parameter `timestamp > (today - 30)`
- I introduce `draft` property and change my idea that new are only the posts with `timestamp > (today - 30) && draft = false`
- I have to change client to add drafts constraint

Note: posts is just an example I am asking in general.

Comment: This depends on what [representation format](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/) the client askes for. As the given samples are similar to [HAL JSON](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) I'd keep the `_links` here on the top-level.

Comment: In spite of my question, does this mean I should discover the alias `/posts/new` by querying `/posts` and reading the `_links` property?

Comment: Did you consider adding the query parameters to the link returned by the service? This way your option 3 would no longer couple client logic to server logic. The client could blindly use the link (that includes query parameters) regardless of what the service considers to be `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a REST architecture URIs should be discovered via their accompanying link-relation name. On interpreting your examples above as [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) the URI `/post/new` has a link-relation name of `new`. Link relation names provide semantics to URIs which allow clients to determine when to invoke these URIs. HAL is just one of a handful JSON-based media types that support HATEOAS. There are [further media-types](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/) available that provide a similar job with slightly different syntax and capabilities.

Upon receiving such a document a client would parse the message and build some context for the message containing the actual content including additional metadata like links and further embedded data. If it wants to retrieve the list of the most recent posts it basically needs to look up the key (link-relation name) that expresses the intent (`new` in your case) from the before-mentioned context in order to retrieve the assigned value (URI). How a client maintains this context is some implementation detail. It might build up a tree-map for easier lookup of "link-relation" keys and their values (URIs) or use some totally different approach.

The knowledge what key to use needs to be present somehow. As link relations express certain semantics they need to be specified somewhere. This can happen in industry standards or media-type definitions. [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) maintains a list of standardized link-relation names and their semantics. On examining the list probably the most likely match according to your specification is `current` which is defined as

> Refers to a resource containing the most recent item(s) in a collection of resources.

I'd therefore propose to change the link-relation name from `new` to `current`.

Comment: I hope I uderstand it correctly that I should somehow (e.g. as a response to `/`) deliver API "map" where the `/posts/new` and other sub links would be listed.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the whole point of the RESTFUL is to make the links discovery easy by making them correspond to the HTTP method used by the client. That means all your links would be simply named `/post`, the only thing that would change is the htpp method and the parameters they take, which your server would use to determine the actual operation the client wants.

This is a sample from a C# project (notice that the links are all the same, the only changes are the `HTTP_METHOD` and/or the parameter passed):

[image]

List of common http methods: `POST, GET, PUT, DELETE`

Comment: Yes, but whole point of HATEAOS and REST is that the api is entirely discoverable by links provided and that the client should (in theory) not need anything other, than the entry endpoint. By this there has to be no definition of the API on the client as all the URLs used are provided by the API itself. "[...] if the engine of application state (and hence the API) is not being driven by hypertext, then it cannot be RESTful and cannot be a REST API" (http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)

Comment: Aliases for common queries (as is `/posts/new`) are then recommended by many. (https://www.kennethlange.com/rest-api-checklist/, https://www.snyxius.com/21-best-practices-designing-launching-restful-api/, https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

Comment: I can't see how this answer addresses the question.