# How to access one element of a REST collection through HATEOAS links?

Tags: spring, rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to build an architecture of RESTful services, and to build a gateway service for all of those, with Java Spring. In order to make the latter, I need to implement a client for the other services, which me and my colleagues tried to design around the HATEOAS principle, by providing links to related resources through spring-hateoas module.

Let's say I have a service running on localhost, listening on 8080 port, which returns a collection of resources with a GET operation on `/resources`. For example:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "resources" : [ {
      "label" : "My first resource!",
      "resourceId" : 3,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/resources/3"
        },
        "meals" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/resources",
          "templated" : true
        }
      }
    }, {
      "label" : "Another resource!",
      "resourceId" : 4,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/resources/4"
        },
        "meals" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/resources",
          "templated" : true
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/resources",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use a HATEOAS client such as Traverson. How could I follow a resource element simply by following HATEOAS links? My solution so far has been to add a link to `item` on my collection, such as follow:

```
"_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/resources",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "item" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/resources/{id}",
      "templated" : true
    }
}
```

So then I can replace the id directly in the template with Traverson and follow the result. But is it a good practice? Should I proceed another way?

Comment: This question sounds pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224620/rest-api-how-to-query-for-links-discovery) IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, Traverson is meant to find a link.

In the simplest cases, each link has a unique name (`rel`). By simply providing the name of the `rel` to Traverson's `follow(...)` function, it will use the proper `LinkDiscoverer` and navigate to the corresponding URI of that `rel`.

This is a `Hop`.

Since the goal is to navigate the API kind of like following links on a webpage, you must define a chain of hops.

In your case, it's a little more complication, since you have an embedded with multiple items. Asking for the `self` link isn't straightforward, since you can easily see three on the root document.

Hence Traverson's support for JSON-Path. If you check the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.25.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#client.traverson), it's easy to see that a JSON-Path expression can be supplied to help pick which link you want.

As long as the attribute being selected is the URI, then Traverson will "hop" to it.

NOTE: When simply using rels, you can supply multiple rels as strings in `follow(...)`. When using anything else, like a JSON-Path expression or `rel(...)`, then use one `follow(...)` **per hop**. Thankfully, this isn't hard to read of you put each hop on a separate line (again, see ref docs for examples).

Comment: I see that my solution wasn't that bad then :) I'll check the use of JSON-paths to see if I can make it prettier. Thank you!