# How do I get Traverson to find a link in a Resource within Resources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am using Traverson to navigate a parent-child relationship of Invoices and Items.  I can get the Resources> and iterate over them to get an individual invoice resource and invoice using a for...each loop.  I want to reuse the Traverson object to get the items for the invoice, but Traverson doesn't want to cooperate for me (yet).

I have looked at the question [How to access one element of a REST collection through HATEOAS links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239726/how-to-access-one-element-of-a-rest-collection-through-hateoas-links), and https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.25.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#client.traverson, which comes close to giving me an answer, but I'm hoping for a more concrete example.

```
String url = baseUrl + invoicesUrl;
Traverson traverson = new Traverson (new URI (url), MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<Invoice>>> invoiceTypeReference = 
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<Invoice>>> () {};
Resources<Resource<Invoice>> invoiceResources =
    traverson.follow ("last").toObject (invoiceTypeReference);

ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<Item>>> itemTypeReference = 
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<Item>>> () {};
for (Resource<Invoice> invoiceResource : invoiceResources) {
    Resources<Resource<Item>> itemResources =
       traverson.follow (invoiceResource.getLink ("items").getRel())
           .toObject(itemTypeReference); // fails to find the link
}
```

Getting the invoice resources works just fine and returns

```
{"_embedded":
  {"invoiceList":
    [{"sourceLastModified":"2019-03-06T22:33:46.000+0000",
      "lastModified":"2019-03-06T22:33:46.000+0000",
      "validFrom":"2019-03-06T22:33:46.000+0000",
      "validTo":"9999-12-31T06:00:00.000+0000",
      "etlStageTagId":null,
      "etlCrTagId":77,
      "etlErrorInd":null,
      "uniqueRowId":35,
      "openRowInd":"Y",
      "id":35,
      "seqNum":1,
      "fileId":null,
      "fileName":null,
      "invoiceNumber":"1",
      "invoiceDate":"2019-01-18T06:00:00.000+0000",
      "invoiceTotal":0.00,
      "companyName":"TEST1",
      "approvedBy":null,
      "approvedOn":null,
      "_links":
        {"self":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/invoices/35"},
         "invoices":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/invoices"},
         "items": {"href":"https://mydomain/myService/items/invoice/1/company/TEST1"},
         "approve":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/invoices/1/TEST1/approve/appName"
        }
      }
    },
    {"sourceLastModified":"2019-03-06T22:33:46.000+0000",
      "lastModified":"2019-03-06T22:33:46.000+0000",
      "validFrom":"2019-03-06T22:33:46.000+0000",
      "validTo":"9999-12-31T06:00:00.000+0000",
      "etlStageTagId":null,
      "etlCrTagId":77,
      "etlErrorInd":null,
      "uniqueRowId":36,
      "openRowInd":"Y",
      "id":36,
      "seqNum":1,
      "fileId":null,
      "fileName":null,
      "invoiceNumber":"1",
      "invoiceDate":"2019-01-18T06:00:00.000+0000",
      "invoiceTotal":-2025.10,
      "companyName":"TEST2",
      "approvedBy":null,
      "approvedOn":null,
      "_links":
        {"self":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/invoices/36"},
         "invoices":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/invoices"},
         "items":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/items/invoice/1/company/TEST2"},
         "approve":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/invoices/1/TEST2/approve/appName"
         }
        }
      }]
    },
  "_links":{"self":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/invoices"},
            "last":{"href":"https://mydomain/myService/invoices/last"
            }
  }
}
```

I expect this code to find the link within the invoice resource to get the items and execute the HTTP GET call.  Instead, I get the error, "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to find link with rel 'items' in response".

How do I get the Traverson object to follow a link within a Resource that I have retrieved within a for...each loop?